# CLPeripheralManager.startAdvertising does not accept return value of CLBeaconRegion.peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower

Tags: ios, swift2, ibeacon, cbperipheralmanager, clbeaconregion

According to the [Swift 2.0 documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeaconRegion_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLBeaconRegion/peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:) for `CLBeaconRegion`, it should still be possible to pass the output of the `peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:` method to the `startAdvertising:` method of `CLPeripheralManager`.

> **Getting Beacon Advertisement Data**
>
> `- peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:`
>
> Retrieves data that can be used to advertise the current device as a beacon.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> ***SWIFT***
>
> `func peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower(_measuredPower: NSNumber?) -> NSMutableDictionary`
>
> ***OBJECTIVE-C***
>
> `- (NSMutableDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull)peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:(NSNumber * _Nullable)measuredPower`
>
> ***Parameters***
>
> `measuredPower`    The received signal strength indicator (RSSI) value (measured in decibels) for the device.
>   This value represents the measured strength of the beacon from one
>   meter away and is used during ranging. Specify `nil` to use the default
>   value for the device.
>
> ***Return Value***
>
> A dictionary of data that you can
>   use in conjunction with a `CBPeripheralManager` to advertise the current
>   device as a beacon.
>
> ***Discussion***
>
> The returned dictionary encodes the beacon’s identifying
>   information along with other information needed to advertise the
>   beacon. You should not need to access the dictionary contents
>   directly. Pass the dictionary to the `startAdvertising:` method of a
>   `CBPeripheralManager` to begin advertising the beacon.
>
> ***Availability***
>
> Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

However, `peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:` returns an `NSMutableDictionary` whereas the `startAdvertising:` method of `CLPeripheralManager` accepts a Swift Dictionary of `[String : AnyObject]?`, although the documentation contends that it accepts an `NSDictionary`. The following code that worked in Swift 1.0:

```
// Set up a beacon region with the UUID, Major and Minor values
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID:beaconUUID!, major:withMajor.unsignedShortValue, minor:withMinor.unsignedShortValue, identifier:"com.example.beacon")

// Attempt to set up a peripheral with the measured power
let peripheralData = region.peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower(withPower) 
_peripheralManager!.startAdvertising(peripheralData)
```

In Swift 2.0 the same code fails to compile with a warning:
 fails to compile, with a warning:

> `NSDictionary` is not convertible to `[String : AnyObject]`; did you
>   mean to use `as!` to force downcast?

However, forcing a downcast always fails.

Is this a documentation bug, a bug in Swift 2.0, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hopefully, somebody better at Swift than me will have an answer.  I am seeing the same thing as you!

Comment: My solution is to cast to a dictionary then an optional cast in the function call.  `let peripheralData = region.peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower(withPower) as Dictionary;
            _peripheralManager!.startAdvertising(peripheralData as? [String : AnyObject])`.

Comment: Yes, that works for me, too.  The key is adding the `as Dictionary`  to the `peripheralData` assignment.  Without it you cannot do the downcast.  I'd love to see somebody offer a more elegant answer, but I have none.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that `NSMutableDictionary` is not easily convertible to Swift's `Dictionary`, but `NSDictinoary` is. So I ended up converting the `NSMutableDictionary` to a `NSDictinoary` first:

```
let pd = NSDictionary(dictionary: region.peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower(nil))
         as! [String: AnyObject]
peripheralManager.startAdvertising(pd)
```

And it works!